# vscode-restclient How to process / parse response body

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-api-testing, vscode-restclient

The [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) extension [vscode-restclient](/questions/tagged/vscode-restclient) allows to create http request and handle the response similar to curl or postman.

A POST request to `/sales/getResult/` returns this response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: ....
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 67
Connection: close

Load your results with ID: CJoYTvh8
```

From the body we need the id `CJoYTvh8` to get details. The request to get details goes to the URL `/sales/GetResult/{{resultId}}` . Where `{{resultId}}` stands for the ID `CJoYTvh8` from the previous response body.

I want to create the request for the details which needs to look like this

```
@resultId = {{myRequest.response.body}}  // this should only be CJoYTvh8

# @name getResult_for_id

POST /sales/getResult/{{resultId}} HTTP/1.1
Host:  {{our_host}}
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

I am looking for something like this

```
@resultId = response.body.split(':')[1].trim()
```

#### Question

How can i split the string `Load your results with ID: CJoYTvh8` in [vscode-restclient](/questions/tagged/vscode-restclient) so that i assign only the id `CJoYTvh8` to the variable `@resultId`?

Comment: support question

Comment: @НиколайМишин it is not clear to me what is meant by `support question`. Just to clarify i did create [vscode-restclient  1058](https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues/1058) for this question.